# Sql Server: mssql_query returns wrong result in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, xampp

I have a stored procedure named `SP_DBA_monitor` that returns exactly 74 rows.

[image: a SQL Server]

But, when I try to call this procedure in the PHP, when I use `mssql_num_rows`, it returns 26. Here is my code:

```
$SQL = "exec SOUNDLOOP.dbo.SP_DBA_monitor";
$result = mssql_query($SQL);
echo (int)mssql_num_rows($result); //Returns 27
```

I know that i'm calling the right procedure because the fewer values it have I can manipulate in the procedure script itself.

I'm using PHP 5.3.5 with XAMPP 1.7.4, in a Windows 7 64 Bits with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: old drivers has problems with sp, try sqlsrv or PDO.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Ok, now it works using sqlsrv. But i'm still having the same problem.